# Django: How to use CSS that's in another file?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

This is probably a stupid question. I'm new to Django and I was wondering how to use CSS when it is in a different file.

Right now, my file paths looks like this:

`CSS: web/static/web/style.css`

`HTML: web/templates/web`

My HTML file looks like this:

```
{% load static %}

<!--HTML-->
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/donate">Donate</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
  .topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
 
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
 
  .topnav a.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
  }
```

How can I get the HTML to use the CSS from a different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `<head>…</head>`tag and type `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/web/style.css"/>` inside the `<head>…</head>` tag.
Make sure the `<head>…</head>` is outside the `<body>…</body>` tag. Here is the new code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/web/style.css"/>
  <!--other head contents like title and meta tag goes here-->
 </head>
 <!--HTML-->
 <body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/donate">Donate</a>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me.

Create a directory called **staticfiles** then inside that folder create a **css** directory.

Then check the settings.py file to make it look like this:

```
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
         'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'myweblabdev.sqlite'),                        
         'USER': '',
         'PASSWORD': '',
         'HOST': '',                      
         'PORT': '',                     
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
```

Then go to the main **urls.py** file of the project and add this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from myweblab import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .......
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And then in the **html** file, add this one and it should work now:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` to `<head></head>` as shown below:

```
{% load static %}

<!--HTML-->
<head>
   {# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'web/style.css' %}">
   {# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/donate">Donate</a>
    </div>
</body>
```